Is there an $S^1$-equivariant continuous map $LX \rightarrow S^1$?
Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $LX$ denote the space of all continuous maps $S^1 \rightarrow X$.
We give $LX$ the compact-open topology as a space of continuous functions. We consider the ``rotation'' action of $S^1$ on $LX$ where $\theta \in S^1$ acts by a precomposition by a rotation by angle $\theta$. (We note this action on $LX$ is continuous.)
My question is whether in general there exists a continuous map $LX \rightarrow S^1$ which is $S^1$-equivariant, for the ``rotation'' action of $S^1$ on $LX$ and the usual rotation action of $S^1$ on itself?
Would anyone know a reference that discusses this, and possible necessary or sufficient conditions for existence of such a map? (I apologize if this is a basic question; I'm not very knowledgeable about loop spaces.)

If you can find a subspace $V\subset LX$ containing one representative from each orbit in $LX/S^1$, such that $V$ admits a continuous map $f:V\to S^1$, then I think you can extend this to a continuous equivariant map $g:LX\to S^1$ via $g(x)=g(sy)=sg(y)$, where $y\in V$ is the representative of $[x]$. Not sure if this helps though, I'm a bit out of my depth.

@Tom I think that makes sense, but I think such a subspace $V$ also needs to be the image of a continuous section of the projection $LX \rightarrow LX / S^1$?

Yep that seems like a good condition to ensure $V$ admits the desired map. I think conceptually what we're after is a continuous "choice of basepoint" for the space of all images of loops in $LX$, which we can then pull back to $LX/S^1$ and will give us a way of constructing the desired $V$ (namely, tell us to use the representative $y$ of each class sending $0$ to the basepoint).

@Tom I agree, I also think an $S^1$-equivariant map $LX \rightarrow S^1$ behaves like a "choice of basepoint" for each loop in $X$, which is perhaps the "same" as a global section of $LX \rightarrow LX/S^1$ in some sense
